# Finding an item in a list in c#

Tags: c#, linq

The code below contains a foreach loop that loops through a list of string collection which contains XML. While enumerating  through the collection, it reads the question and answer elements and adds them to the list collection. I need to ensure that no repeated question is added to the list collection.

The code below `questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers)` adds the elements to the list collection. The problem that I am facing is that the repeated questions are getting added to the list. I tried to put the following condition that is:

```
if (questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Find(a => a.Question != fataQuestionsAnswers.Question) == null)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

```
var fataQuestionnaireData = DbAccess.GetFatcaQuestionnaire(contactId);
if (fataQuestionnaireData != null)
{
    var questionnaire = new FatcaQuestionnaire();

    foreach (var fatcaQuestionnaire in fataQuestionnaireData)
    {
        //var QData = GetObjectFromStream<FatcaQuestionnaire>fataQuestionnaireData);
        //FatcaQuestionnaire.Deserialize(fataQuestionnaireData);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(fatcaQuestionnaire.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

        // w.WriteLine("The value of doc" + doc);

        doc.Descendants("QuestionAnswer").ToList().ForEach(questionAnswer =>
        {
            var fataQuestionsAnswers = new QuestionAnswers();
            {
                //var questionAnswer = qa.Element("QuestionAnswer");

                var questionElement = questionAnswer.Element("Question");


                if (questionElement != null )

                    fataQuestionsAnswers.Question = questionElement.Value;

                //if (questionElement != null)
                //    w.WriteLine("The value of questionElement" + questionElement.Value);

                var answerElement = questionAnswer.Element("Answer");
                if (answerElement != null)
                    fataQuestionsAnswers.Answer = answerElement.Value;

                //if (answerElement != null)
                //    w.WriteLine("The value of answerElement" + answerElement.Value);

                var sqa = questionAnswer.Element("SubQuestionAnswer");
                if (sqa != null)

                {
                    var subQuestionElement = sqa.Element("Question");
                    if (subQuestionElement != null)
                        fataQuestionsAnswers.SubQuestionAnswer.Question = subQuestionElement.Value;

                    //if (subQuestionElement != null)
                    //    w.WriteLine("The value of answerElement" + subQuestionElement.Value);


                    var subAnswerElement = sqa.Element("Answer");
                    if (subAnswerElement != null)
                        fataQuestionsAnswers.SubQuestionAnswer.Answer = subAnswerElement.Value;

                    //if (subQuestionElement != null)
                    //    w.WriteLine("The value of answerElement" + subQuestionElement.Value);
                }

                if (questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Find(a => a.Question != fataQuestionsAnswers.Question) == null)
                questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers);
                //fatcaQuestionsList.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers);
            }

            fatca.Questionnaire.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why not `if(!questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Any(a => a.Question != fataQuestionsAnswers.Question)) { questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers); }`

Comment: @Tom please understand the difference between a for loop and a foreach loop they are not the same edit your question as well as fix the formatting thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your condition wrong, you are looking for `questionanswers` where the `question` does not match, you should be looking where they do match and checking that the result is null. (switch the != with ==)

It should be

```
if (questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Find(a => a.Question == fataQuestionsAnswers.Question) == null)
```

However I would change it to `Any()` as it is a bit nearer and easier to read, it returns a true if one of the items in your list matches the condition that you specify.

```
if(!questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Any(a => a.Question == fataQuestionAnswers.Question)) {
   questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers);
}
```

Comment: It still adds duplicate questions.

Comment: In `questionaire.QuestionAnswers` or `fatca.Questionnaire`, you are still adding `fataQuestionAnswers` to `fatca.Questionnaire`, not sure what that is. I'll be honest i'm struggling to follow the code example. Also you are checking the strings exactly match, could there be a case difference?

Comment: Thanks everybody. I had to push the second logic in the if condition for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any` instead

```
if(!questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Any(a => a.Question == fataQuestionsAnswers.Question)) 
{ 
    questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers); 
}
```

Comment: @Tom If that doesn't work `a.Question` and ` fataQuestionsAnswers.Question` cannot be compared. What datatypes are the Question objects?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there's trailing spaces / casing differences?

```
if(!questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Any(a => a.Question.Trim().Equals(fataQuestionsAnswers.Question.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) 
{ 
    questionnaire.QuestionAnswers.Add(fataQuestionsAnswers); 
}
```